# How to modify a value of a Nifi configuration file in manifest?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi

I have value that I would like to change in configuration file.
The value I would like to change is nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled=true to false.

I tried the following in my manifest, adding:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tests-nifi
  namespace: poc
  labels:
    name : tests-nifi
    app : tests-nifi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tests-nifi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tests-nifi
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: nifi
        image: apache/nifi
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: nifi
        env:
        - name: "NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY"
          value: "nificluster"
        - name: ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN
          value: "no"
        - name: SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME 
          value: nifi-user
        - name: SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD 
          value: nifi-user-password
        - name: NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST
          value: "0.0.0.0"
        - name: NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT
          value: "8080"
        - name: NIFI_ANALYTICS_PREDICT_ENABLED
          value: "true"
        - name: NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_CANDIDATES
          value: "1"
        - name: NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT
          value: "20 sec"
        - name: NIFI_JVM_HEAP_INIT
          value: "2g"
        - name: NIFI_JVM_HEAP_MAX
          value: "4g"
        - name: NIFI_CONTENT_REPOSITORY_ARCHIVE_ENABLED
          value: "false"
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
              - pgrep
              - java
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 3
          successThreshold: 1
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
              port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 240
          periodSeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 3
          successThreshold: 1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 2
            ephemeral-storage: 2Gi
            memory: 4Gi
          limits:
            cpu: 8
            ephemeral-storage: 2Gi
            memory: 16Gi
```

I added:

```
- name: NIFI_CONTENT_REPOSITORY_ARCHIVE_ENABLED
  value: "false"
```

But when I do exec in the pod the value nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled is still true. The value to change is in the file named "nifi.properties".

How can I do it to change the value in my yaml ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not directly familiar with Apache Nifi, but a little bit of research suggests:

- A StatefulSet is a better approach than a deployment
- The configuration file likely needs to be loaded into the pod to set that value, rather then trying to set it as an environment variable - this would be done with a ConfigMap
- You could look at using a helm chart to help deploy it, along with being able to make configuration changes a bit easier.

Some resources:

- https://github.com/cetic/helm-nifi
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/data/helm-deployments-apache-nifi
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/

The shortest path for you to apply your change (if not looking at helm, statefulsets, etc), is to copy your full apache nifi config(s) into a ConfigMap and mount that into your deployment - though this is likely only good for your test and shouldn't be used for production.

Just an example, not a complete spec:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: apache-nifi-config
data:
  nifi.properties: | 
  ... 
  nifi.flow.configuration.archive.enabled=false

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tests-nifi
  namespace: poc
  labels:
    name : tests-nifi
    app : tests-nifi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tests-nifi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tests-nifi
    spec:
    ...
      containers:
        - name: nifi
          volumeMounts:
          - name: nifi-properties
            mountPath: "/nifi-properities-path"
            readOnly: true
    ...
      volumes:
      - name: "nifi-properties"
        configMap:
          name: apache-nifi-config
          items:
            - key: "nifi.properties"
              path: "nifi.properties"
```